# Use external scss variables in inline Angular components' style

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

I'm using Angular and `scss` for a webapp, and I'm facing some problems when I try to use scss variables in inline components' style.

I have a `_variables.scss` containing a bunch of variables that I'd like to use, but if I try this:

```
styles: [`
  @import '../_variables.scss';
  ...
  ...
```

Though the build is completed successfully, I receive the following error in the console:

```
Failed to load ../_variables.scss
```

The toggle of the prefixing underscore doesn't fix the problem.

I also tried:

```
styleUrls: ['../_variables.scss'],
```

and it doesn't emit any error, but when I try to access a variable it doesn't get parsed.

How can I use scss in inline compoenents style?

Comment: I wondered if the problem wasn't the variables but scss itself, so I searched and I found this issue on github, opened by sir John Papa:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8470
I don't delete the question because I want to know about workarounds, please don't downvote :)

Comment: By the way, I think I can forget the flat folder structure since it's giving me a lot of problems